# Is the region of convergence of Laplace transforms of a right-sided signal right of the rightmost pole?

Tags: laplace-transform

I know that the ROC of a right-sided signal with a rational Laplace transform is right of the rightmost pole. Does it apply to any right-sided signal?

Comment: I replaced right-handed with right-sided, but your question still doesn't make sense to me. If you know the ROC of a right-sided signal, why are you asking if it applies to, again, a right-sided signal? If you mean whether or not it applies to left-sided signals, then I believe the ROC is left of the leftmost pole.

Comment: @SvenB I think OP is asking about signals whose Laplace transform are not in the format of the "*ratio of polynomials*". e.g. \$\delta(t-t_0) \leftrightarrow e^{-t_0 s}\$.

Comment: @AJN Yes, that's the case. What is the pole of $$\ e^{-t_0 s}$$  .From Taylor series expansion, it has infinity order polynomial.